# jQuery clone element and insertAfter

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone a simple div and insert it after itself:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // clone and append
  $("div").clone().appendTo("div");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 10px; background-color: blue; width: 600px; margin-bottom:1px"></div>
```

Why is this not working as I expect it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append to a parent container instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // clone and append
  $("div").clone().text('cloned div').appendTo("body");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color: blue; width: 600px; margin: bottom:1px">original div</div>
```

`appendTo('div')` did not work because it inserted the cloned div at the end but **within** the existing div.

Comment: Thanks. jQuery says the following about appendTo:` Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.`  How come my code above did not do that?

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks. This line from jQuery docs solved it as you explained: `With .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container.`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to insert the element after the exsisting one, then you shoud use `.inserftAfter()`

```js
$(() => {
  $('div').clone().insertAfter('div');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 25px; background-color: blue; width: 25px; margin-bottom:1px"></div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to make it more obvious that the `<div>` has been inserted. Maybe add some CSS margin so the two elements are separated?

Comment: Upon closer inspection,  maybe `margin: bottom:1px` is intended to be `margin-bottom:1px`.